# AnyLogic if condition selectOutput

Tags: anylogic

I'm modelling a manufacturing line in anylogic. Two agents are being processed and transported via the same conveyor. Both Agents need to spend diffent delay times in a service station. Because of that i added two parallel services and now i want to sort the agents arriving on the conveyor to their corrosponding service stations.

[flowchart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4R8b.png)

Agent1 needs to go to service and Agent2 to serviceT.
I assigned parameters to both Agents, Agent1 has the boolean parameter "S" set to true and Agent2 the same parameter set to false.
To sort the Agents in the selectOutput block i typed in the if condition `agent.S == true`  as seen in the next screenshot.

[selectOutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vxSU.png)

Anylogic prompts following error: "Unresolved compilation problem: S cannot be resolved or is not a field"

What can i do about this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to answer this question in two parts:

1. Instead of using a selectOutput to model different delay times for the SAME station, it would be more reasonable to have only ONE service representing that ONE station. To model different times, set the delay time equal to agent.S where S is the delay time for each agent.
2. Regardless of whether you choose what I suggested or what you are already using, you will still get the same error. The reason for this error is most likely that you haven't specified the agent type going through the select output properly. In fact, if you look at the image of the select output properties you shared, under the "Advanced" tab, the agent type is set as the default type `Agent`. Make sure to replace that by the agent type that contains the parameter S.

Comment: Thank you for your response!

1. I have thought about that before i came up with the other solution. But i couldnt figure out how to code that.

2. I lef the Agent Type set on the default Agent, because i didnt knew whcih Agent to selct. Can i manually select 2 Agents?

Comment: Where did you define the S parameter?

Comment: I dragged a parameter component into both Agents and named it S. Then defined it as boolean and set it true for Agent1 and false for Agent2.

Comment: What determines the value of S whether true or false? Random?

Comment: Its statically set for both Agents, basically just to tell them apart.

Comment: I would recommend you use only one agent type for both and on startup field of the agent type have something like: S = randomTrue(0.5); This will have half your agents with an S value true and another half of a value false

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. I will have to redo the rest of my model aswell but it should make things easier once im beyond this step and add more features.

Comment: One more thing just came to my mind:
Im curious if i can get this iteration to work for now to review some first results. Can i somehow add two agent types to the advanced tab of the selectOutput block? In the drop down menu i can only selct one at a time.

Comment: Not sure, but I wouldn't recommend it